# Javascript method document.querySelector alternative in VueJs for optimization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, queryselector

I need to optimize my code with all features of VueJs, so i've changed all the document.getElementById and document.querySelectorAll by using the ref in VueJs

So the only thing that i dont found an alternative is how to change :
document.querySelector with another code related to VueJs :

```
document.querySelector('.mc-layer__content').classList.add('disable-scroll')
```

Is there any optimization related to this ?

Another important point, i can't use the ref here because the class is in the parent no in the component, so when i use this.$refs i can't see the parent element.

Comment: Even refs are not really ideal, they are supposed to be a last resort. Proper Vue is to use props and bindings. To add or remove a class, you use this: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax

Comment: We are using the v2 not v3

Comment: Right, so this then: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html My point still stands, this basic mechanism has existed from v1.

Comment: We can use it if the class is in the parent and access in the child ?

Comment: You can use props to pass stuff down from the parent. This includes functions. Put the bool in the parent's state, and a method to toggle/set it. Then pass them down to the child as needed.

Comment: I need to use emit to pass data from child to parent to can change the class but the parent isnt a direct parent, so i dont know if i can use emit in this case

Comment: I haven't really used Vue yet but it should be possible to emit events further up the tree I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data () {
    return {
      scroll: true
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.disable-scroll {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="scroll = !scroll">switch</button>
  <div class="mc-layer__content" :class="{'disable-scroll': scroll}">
    ssssss
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I downvoted this because this answer is just rehashing a basic part of the official docs.

Comment: Not really anything wrong with the answer @NikolaPavicevic, but if you are answering direct from the docs try and encourage the user asking the question to read a bit further into the docs as well. Always worth helping people get to grips with finding the info if it's there in the docs 

Comment: @Nikola, i'm searching the way how to use the class binding because : the class is in the parent (not direct parent, level 2) and the event occur in child (the emit doesnt work)

Comment: I've used the store for the optimization like this : this.$store.dispatch('app/disableScroll')

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i've foud is to use the store because the parent isnt direct :

In the child component instead to use document.querySelector,

```
document.querySelector('.mc-layer__content').classList.remove('disable-scroll')
```

i've used :

```
this.$store.dispatch('app/disableScroll')
```

And in the parent, i've add the dynamic class :

```
:class="{ 'disable-scroll': isDisabled }"
```

The variable isDisabled has been managed in the store with disableScroll variable like this:

```
disableScroll(state) {
      state.disableScroll = true
    },
    enableScroll(state) {
      state.disableScroll = false
    },
```